# I want to calculate percentage in template with django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I want to calculate and show the discount interest of the product in the template. I tried something like below but it didn't work. Is there a practical way to do this?

index.html

```
{% if product.sale %}
<span class="sale">{{((product.price - product.sale) / product.price) * 100}}</span>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You don't. Such logic does *not* belong in the template. Django's template language is *deliberately* restricted to prevent people from writing this logic in the template.

Comment: How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't**. Such logic does *not* belong in the template. Django's template language is *deliberately* restricted to prevent people from writing this logic in the template.

Usually you write this in the model, for example as a propertly, like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # …
    
    @property
    def price_percentage(self):
        return 100 * (self.price - self.sale) / self.price
```

then in the template you can render this as:

```
{% if product.sale %}
    <span class="sale">{{ product.price_percentage }}</span>
{% endif %}
```